Send audible alert if disk is 90% full
I'd like an audible alert if the Windows 11 system Hard Drive exceeds 90%. I have a working powershell script to send the alert, how can i expand on this to detect if the drive is getting full?
$PlayWav=New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$PlayWav.SoundLocation=’C:\Users\ReoPC\Documents\sirenwail.wav’
$PlayWav.playsync()

